# Handling failed promises in jasmine

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner

I'm very newbie in jasmine!

I have the a service with the following code

```
function getSomeData() { 
            return $http(
                    {
                        method: 'GET',
                        url: $localStorage.serverName + 'w_service_json.get_wf_proc?pn_login_id='  + sessionService.getUserId()
                    }).then(function (response) {
                                var lv_json = JSON.stringify(response.data);
                                var myArr = JSON.parse(lv_json);
                                return myArr;
                            }).catch(function (err) {//console.log(err);
                                var val = err.message || (err.status==-1?'server error':'error');
                                errService.add(val);
                                return err; 
                            });
        }
```

and a error handling service (errService) as follows:

```
angular
        .module('err')
        .service('errService', errService);

    errService.$inject = ['$mdDialog'];
    function errService($mdDialog) {
        var self = this;
        var erros=[];
        self.add = add;
        self.show = show;

        return self;

        function add(err)
        {
            erros.push(err);
            throw err;
        }
```

I need to make sure the service is handling errors so I've made a test in jasmine:

```
beforeEach(inject(function (_errService_,_$rootScope_,_sessionService_,_wfActivitiesRemoteService_,_$localStorage_,_$state_, $httpBackend) {

    $scope=_$rootScope_;
    errService=_errService_;
    wfActivitiesRemoteService = _wfActivitiesRemoteService_;
    state=_$state_;
    $localStorage=_$localStorage_;
    $localStorage.serverName="http://someserverip/";
    sessionService=_sessionService_;
    httpBackend = $httpBackend;
    httpBackend.whenGET(/\.html$/).passThrough();

  }));

  it("sem sessao", function () {

    spyOn(sessionService, "getUserId").and.returnValue("");

    httpBackend.expectGET('http://someserverip/w_service_json.get_wf_proc?pn_login_id=').respond(-1,errServer);

    var test=function(data)
    {
          expect(data).toEqual('');
          console.log("test");
    };
    var fail=function(err)
    {
        expect(err).not.toBeUndefined();
        console.log("fail");
    };   

    var run=function()
    {
        wfActivitiesRemoteService.getSomeData().then(test).catch(fail);
    };

    expect(function() {wfActivitiesRemoteService.getSomeData}).toThrow('server error');
    run();

    httpBackend.flush();


});
```

I'm not beeing able to enter inside the function fail! The promise in the service fails and the test automatically fails without entering the catch inside the test!

How can I solve this?
What's the correct way to solve this?

Comment: The right way to do it would be to use `$httpBackend.whenGET()` and tell it how to respond so that it hits your catch. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend#whenGET

Comment: The use of `toThrow` assertion isn't correct (besides the fact that getSomeData isn't called there). Rejected promises don't throw.

Comment: getSomeData wasn't being called beacause of a typo. sorry!

Comment: If I use whenGet instead of expectGet it won't wait for the call exiting the test before it, it won't accept the http.flush and gives me a false success without entering neither functions. http://ng-learn.org/2014/08/Testing_Promises_with_Jasmine/

Comment: without expecting toThrow I get this: test sem sessao FAILED
 server error thrown. With expecting to thow I get: test sem sessao FAILED
 Expected function to throw an exception.ServiceSpec.js:118:40
 loaded@http://localhost:9876/context.js:151:17
 server error thrown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution! The exception needed to be catch in the test and not in the promise! So I had to change the code to:

```
var test=function(data)
    {
        console.log("test:"+data);  
        expect(data).toEqual('');

    };
    var fail=function(err)
    {
        console.log("fail");
        expect(err).not.toBeUndefined();
        expect(err).toEqual('server error');

    };   
    var run=function()
    {
        console.log('run');
        wfActivitiesRemoteService.getSomeData().then(test).finally(done);
    };
    try
    {
        spyOn(sessionService, "getUserId").and.returnValue("");

        httpBackend.expectGET('http://someserverip/w_service_json.get_wf_proc?pn_login_id=').respond(-1,errServer);
        run();
        httpBackend.flush();
    }
    catch(err)
    {
        console.log("catch");
        fail(err);
    }
    finally
    {
        console.log("finally");
        done();
    }
```

I still think that probably there's a way to test it with the promise, but in this way I'm already able to capture and test the error.

Comment: I think you could remove the `.finally(done)`, as you would be calling it on the `finally {...}` after the `catch`. Some expert confirming this would be **greatly** appreciated